# Setup max-threads parameter to the Thorntail JBeret fraction

Tags: wildfly-swarm, jberet, thorntail

I use JBeret Thorntail Fraction (thorntail version - 2.0.0.Final):

What is the proper way to define max-threads number?

When I set up yaml configuration:

```
swarm: 
  batch:
    thread-pools:
      default:
        max-threads: 20
```

Max thread count remains 10 (default value).

Should in this case I define my own thread pool and how to do this?

It seems that any batch fractions properties I defined are ignored and set to default values. I tried, for example:

```
datasources:
  data-sources:
    h2:
      driver-name: h2
      connection-url: jdbc:h2:./target/jberet-repo
      user-name: sa
      password: sa
batch:
  default-job-repository: h2
  jdbc-job-repositories:
    h2:
      data-source: h2
  thread-pools:
    batch:
      max-threads: 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just today, we found that we have a docs issue (see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-2364). The correct configuration keys aren't `swarm.batch.*`, but `swarm.batch-jberet.*` (or rather `thorntail.*` instead of `swarm.*` :-) ).

Knowing that, and knowing that the default thread pool isn't called `default` but `batch`, your YAML config should look like this:

```
swarm: 
  batch-jberet:
    thread-pools:
      batch:
        max-threads: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if it's hard coded: https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/blob/master/fractions/javaee/batch-jberet/src/main/java/org/wildfly/swarm/batch/jberet/BatchFraction.java#L75

Please raise an issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN describing the problem

Comment: Thanks, Ken, I will raise an issue

Comment: It seems the default thread pool is called `batch`, not `default`.